# Split array into multiple array's or alternate - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, var

I have an array

```
var array = ['123.456789,123.1','456.7890123,234.1','789.0123456,345.1'];
```

The outcome I'm looking for is

```
var array1 = [123.456789,456.7890123,789.0123456];
var array2 = [123.1,234.1,345.1];
```

What's best practice for doing this?
I've been looking at
    .split("");
but would like to know the best way to approach it.

Thanks in advance
Mach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var arr = ["123.456789,123.1","456.7890123,234.1","789.0123456,345.1"];

var array1 = [],
    array2 = arr.map(function(e) {
        e = e.split(",");
        array1.push(+e[0]);
        return +e[1];
    });

console.log(array1, array2);
```

Comment: why the plus sign in **+e[0]**? Is it the same as a cast?

Comment: @letiagoalves Yep, it's a shorcut for `Number(e[0])`.

Answer (score 3):

I think that you should go with **split** function. Try this or see this [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ukoraz/2/edit/):

```
var array = ['123.456789,123.1','456.7890123,234.1','789.0123456,345.1'];
var array1 = [], array2 = [];

for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
   array1[i] = array[i].split(",")[0];
   array2[i] = array[i].split(",")[1];
}
```

Comment: [Don't use `var i in array` syntax to iterate arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/javascript-for-in-with-arrays).

Comment: @Jack what do you sugest? `for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++)` style?

Comment: Yep, that would be better :) you can also cache the array length in a local variable (micro optimization though).

Answer (score 1):

Basically you should iterate over the array and for each item you split the string into two parts, based on the comma. Each part goes into their respective array.

If [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is allowed:

```
var a1 = [], a2 = [];

array.forEach(function(item) {
  var parts = item.split(',');
  a1.push(+parts[0]);
  a2.push(+parts[1]);
}
```

Otherwise:

```
var a1 = [], a2 = [];

for (var i = 0, item; item = array[i]; ++i) {
  var parts = item.split(',');
  a1.push(+parts[0]);
  a2.push(+parts[1]);
}
```

Comment: In your case it is better to use `Array.forEach`.

Comment: @VisioN Don't remember using that before ... ah yes, that's a lot better :)